# Enforcing properties of an object to be from the listed ones in a JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

How can I enforce the "object" property only to allow the listed properties be part of it and not something else, especially an empty key ""?

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "object": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property3": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, what you are looking for is `"additionalProperties": false`.

Below is your schema with `additionalProperties` added. See here to try it out: https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/RDGrQvL6

Note that I had to remove the extra `"object"` wrapper from your schema to make it work.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "property1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "property2": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "property3": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: I see but that is not working for me, I need the nested structure, this is just an example my schema is more complex than this.

Comment: Sure, but then you would likely be pointing to it from some other place of the schema by means of `$ref`. In any case, `additionalProperties: false` prevents the schema from allowing any properties not listed under `properties`.

Comment: Okay, thanks you are right, what I forgot to put in the root object is a "type": "object" and that is what caused it not to work for me, I will update the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer is correct and `"additionalProperties": false` is the right thing that I needed, but here is the code in terms of what I actually wanted to achieve with the nested object.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "object": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property2": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "property3": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "additionalProperties": false // will not allow any other property other than 'property1', 'property2' or 'property3' as part of the nested object "object".
    }
  }
}
```